# What is the size of Range?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Suppose d=gcd$(a,n)$ where $a, n \in \mathbb{Z}, n>0$ and

$f_a: \mathbb{Z_n} \to \mathbb{Z_n} \\
\qquad x \to ax\texttt{ mod } n$

The size of Domain is evident and for the size of Range my reasonings are as follows.
$$0\cdot a \equiv 0 \texttt{ mod } n \\
\vdots \qquad \vdots \qquad \vdots \\
k \cdot a \equiv 0 \texttt{ mod } n$$
Where $k$ is the smallest +ve integer in $ \mathbb{Z_n}$. From above we have $n \mid k \cdot a \implies (\frac{n}{d}) \mid k \cdot (\frac{a}{d}) \implies (\frac{n}{d}) \mid k \qquad$ because $(\frac{n}{d}) \nmid (\frac{a}{d})$

Hence, the size of the Range $k = (\frac{n}{d})$

Is there any other way to prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $d= \lambda a + \mu n \equiv \lambda a \mod{n}$, and $a= kd$.

$f_a$ is a group morphism. Applying the first isomorphism theorem, the order of the image is
$$|\operatorname{Im}f_a| = |\Bbb{Z}_n / \ker f_a | = \frac{n}{|\ker f_a|}$$
Now, $\ker f_a = \{ x : ax \equiv 0 \mod{n} \} = \{ x : dx \equiv 0 \mod{n} \}$ has size $d$, so you have the result.

It remains to show that $$ax \equiv 0 \mod{n} \Leftrightarrow dx \equiv 0 \mod{n}$$
This is clear because $a$ and $d$ divide each other $\mod{n}$ from
$$d= \lambda a \mod{n}$$
$$a= kd \mod{n}$$